# How can I inject SQL into my site?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm quite new to SQL injection and I think my code is very vulnerable to be injected. But I tried using

```
1 OR 1=1; DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS]; -- as a username and 
OR 1=1; as a password in

$sql ="SELECT * FROM student_2556 WHERE stu_code = '$user' AND stpass = '$pass' ";

$result = mysql_db_query($dbname, $sql);
```

How can I get it injected and drop all of the tables?

Comment: Don't just try random snippets you have found on the internet, try to think at what the generated request would look like once you have replaced the variables. If you do that, you will easily be able to come with something to do what you want.

Comment: I agree with @FlorentBayle. If your site has a search form for example, try entering the injection string in there, or any other places where user input is sent to the server.

Comment: Well, it's only the online registration site so the username and password is the only way to send injecting code in. And the snippets that I've found handy is 'OR''='

Answer (score 3):

Since your variables are enclosed in quotation marks, you could in theory be able to SQL inject by adding in another quotation mark, eg, passing in a password:

```
1 '; DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS]; '
--^ ends the previous value assignment
```

This turns your sql into:

```
SELECT * FROM student_2556 WHERE stu_code = '$user' AND stpass = '1 '; DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS]; ''
```

Though if your goal is to prevent SQL injection, all you need to do is properly parameterize your input variables and you don't have to worry about it!

Comment: Yeah. I've already fixed it at the production site using mysql_real_escape_string($data);
I just want to test it if it's possible to drop all the table without prepared statement